# Getting RGB at Runtime from color

Tags: android, colors

I want to extract the RGB value from color

My color is declared in xml as

```
<color name="color_primary">#009688</color>
```

Now I want the RGB value of this in my `Activity` at runtime.
How to convert `color_primary` in `Color` object ?
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your color is an int. You can use

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary);
```

in `onCreate` of your `Activity`. If you need the RGB components of your color, you can use the Color class:

```
int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
```